# items sliders not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am having a problem with my html code ,the problem is that i am trying to create a item slider if that what it's called, in my case i am having 9 items i wanna show only maybe 5 of them and when someone click on the rectangle it will slide to the left and show him the 3 left brands ,but everytime i am trying to do that nothing happening ,for more explanation please check my code:

```
    <div id="tf-clients" class="text-center">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="section-title center">
                <h2>Some of <strong>our Clients</strong></h2>
                <div class="line">
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="clients" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
                <div class="owl-wrapper-outer autoHeight" style="height: 121px;"><div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 3192px; left: 0px; display: block;"><div class="owl-item" style="width: 228px;"><div class="item">
                    <img src="img/client/01.png">
                </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 228px;"><div class="item">
                    <img src="img/client/02.png">
                </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 228px;"><div class="item">
                    <img src="img/client/03.png">
                </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 228px;"><div class="item">
                    <img src="img/client/04.png">
                </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 228px;"><div class="item">
                    <img src="img/client/05.png">
                </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 228px;"><div class="item">
                    <img src="img/client/06.png">
                </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 228px;"><div class="item">
                    <img src="img/client/07.png">
                </div></div></div></div>

            <div class="owl-controls clickable"><div class="owl-pagination"><div class="owl-page active"><span class=""></span></div><div class="owl-page"><span class=""></span></div></div></div></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

as u can see this is my code and it has 9 images and i've create a span tag so to create a rectangles so when i click on the span it will show me the other hidden images by sliding them left ,but it's seems not working did i do something wrong please give me a hand anything it will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: What library are you using, for the library?

Comment: i don't know what do u mean ,but i just followed a template that using the same thing ,and i am working on it but it's seem not to work https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/spirit-8-corporate-multipurpose-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/ this is the template SOME OF OUR CLIENTS it's the same result i am having just the orange rectangles are not fonctioning to switch to other brands thanks

Comment: i don't understand the problem, sorry.. looks like it's boostrap. Make sure that the JS files are included as well as `jQuery.js`

Comment: the two files are included thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just recently practicing with something similar myself. This is what I came up with, see if it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/v3kLwh0o/

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
   <div class="arrows">
      <div class="left"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg"></i></div>
      <div class="right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg"></i></div>
   </div>

   <ul class="slides">
      <li class="slide one"></li>
      <li class="slide two"></li>
      <li class="slide three"></li>
      <li class="slide one"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider-wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

.slider-wrapper > .slides {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 2880px; /* 720*4(pictures) */
    height: 400px;
}

.one { background-color: blue; }
.two { background-color: green; }
.three { background-color: red; }

.slider-wrapper > .slides .slide {
    width: 720px; /* 720px */
    height: 400px; /* 400px */
    float: left;
}

.slider-wrapper > .arrows {
    margin: 170px 0; /* (400-60[height of arrow container])/2 */
    position: absolute;
    width: 720px;
}

.slider-wrapper > .arrows > .left, .slider-wrapper > .arrows > .right {
    height: 60px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 20px 0; /* (60-20[height of arrow])/2 */
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.slider-wrapper > .arrows > .left:hover, .slider-wrapper > .arrows > .right:hover {
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-wrapper > .arrows > .left { float: left; }
.slider-wrapper > .arrows > .right { float: right; }
```

JS:

```
// Set quantified variables
        var width = 720;
        var animationSpeed = 1000;
        var slideCount = 1;

        // Set variables to cache the DOM tree parts that are needed (makes performance faster since the program doesn't have to go through the entire tree everytime)
        var $leftArrow = $('.arrows > .left');
        var $rightArrow = $('.arrows > .right');

        var $slider = $('.slider-wrapper > .slides');
        var $slides = $slider.find('.slide');

        // Runs when the left arrow is clicked
        $leftArrow.click(function() {
            $slider.animate({'margin-left':'-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
                // After the animation ends, increase counter and check to see if its on the last image
                slideCount++;
                if (slideCount == $slides.length) {
                    slideCount = 1;
                    $slider.css('margin-left','0');
                }

                // console.log("Left: " + slideCount);
            });
        });

        // Runs when the right arrow is clicked
        $rightArrow.click(function() {
            // Check to see if slider is on the first image (which it is initially)
            // If it is, change the left margin of the slider to (number of images - 1) * width * -1 (i.e. margin-left of the last image)
            var firstImageCheck = function() {
                if (slideCount == 1) {
                    slideCount = $slides.length;
                    lastPicMargin = width * ($slides.length-1) * -1;
                    $slider.css('margin-left', lastPicMargin);
                }
            }

            firstImageCheck();

            $slider.animate({'margin-left':'+='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
                // After the animation ends, decrease counter and check to see if its on the first image
                slideCount--;
                firstImageCheck();
                // console.log("Right: " + slideCount);
            });
        });
```

Comment: thanks for u're help Bazinga, but i guess u got me wrong what i am trying to do is like in this template https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/spirit-8-corporate-multipurpose-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/ scroll down to "SOME OF OUR CLIENTS" u can see some brand showing and when u click on the orange rectangle it will slide the other brands check the image for more explanation thanks http://www6.0zz0.com/2015/08/15/15/974918548.jpg

Comment: okay I made some minor edits to the original and hopefully now it serves your purpose: http://jsfiddle.net/v3kLwh0o/2/

Comment: thank u very very much Man it's working thanks a lot